# Can't use " this.getRef(position).getKey(); " in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter From FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

After this update in Firebase it has caused real issues n I'm stuck at this thing

`keyFire = this.getRef(position).getKey();`

The `getKey()` method is no longer working with it n causing error..

`Cannot resolve method 'getKey()'`

Here's the code:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Boolean, FriendsViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Boolean, FriendsViewHolder>(
                Boolean.class,  R.layout.chat_view_list, FriendsViewHolder.class, friendsRef){

            protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, Boolean model, final int position) {

       --> -->       keyFire = this.getRef(position).getKey();
                keyhold=keyFire;
                final DatabaseReference  mFirebaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(constants.FIREBASE_URL+"rootssahaj/authGplus");

                mFirebaseRef.child(keyFire).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {


                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String name = dataSnapshot.child("userNAME").getValue(String.class);
                                String picurl = dataSnapshot.child("picurl").getValue(String.class);
                                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.e("SahajLOG", "DATASNApshot  " +dataSnapshot+ "  name " +name);
                        if(name==null){

                            dialogLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Mcontext);

                        prefs.edit().putString("OtherUserNames"+position,name).commit();
                        Log.e("SahajLOG", "POSITION   " +position+"  " +dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        prefs.edit().putString("OtherEmail"+position , dataSnapshot.getKey()).commit();
                        prefs.edit().putString("UserEmail",EmailPref).commit();
                        viewHolder.mName.setText(name);
                                viewHolder.mStatus.setText(status);
                                Picasso.with(context).load(picurl).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(viewHolder.mImageProfile);
                    }

                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) { }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Works for me: `Log.d(TAG, "populateViewHolder: key="+getRef(position).getKey());` -> `05-23 07:18:00.213 ... populateViewHolder: key=-KFlChRljg-MmHLBa8YS`. Here's the relevant [code in Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L150) and the relevant [method in the reference doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#public-methods). Is there anything more you can say about the problem?

Comment: it was working previously But **After Upgrading to new Firebase Api from old legacy firebase api** it shows tht error

Comment: My code is also after upgrading. We use that call internally quite a bit, so I'm surprised it doesn't work for you.

Comment: okie.. thnks i got it  the Api Reference is chnged to `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

`adapter.getRef(position).getKey();`

Comment: Add context around your answer for future learning purpose and downvote prevention. (From Review).